# Python - Callback from method to another class

Tags: python, multithreading, class, object

Great fellows !

I read lot of topics about this subject but I can't make it works.

This is my exemple script :

```
import time, threading, collections


class Factory () :

    def __init__(self):
        self.to_do_list = collections.deque()

    def run(self):
        while self.to_do_list :
            new_task = self.to_do_list.popleft()
            new_task.start(self.done_callback)

    def add_worker(self, task):
        self.to_do_list.append(task)

    def done_callback(self):
            print("OK - DONE")

class Worker (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, _name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = _name

    def run(self, _callback):
        self.callback = _callback
        for i in range (0,5):
            print(self.name+" -- "+str(i))
            time.sleep(0.5)     
        self.callback()

worker_1 = Worker("Anakin")
worker_2 = Worker("Obi-Wan")
worker_3 = Worker("Yoda")

factory = Factory()

factory.add_worker(worker_1)
factory.add_worker(worker_2)
factory.add_worker(worker_3)

factory.run()
```

When I run my Workers with `run(self.done_callback)` it's working well but I loose the multi-threading effect.

And if I run it with the `start(self.done_callback)` I'm facing this error message : `TypeError: start() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Can you explain to me what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your time !

Answer (score 1):

First, when you run your workers with `new_task.start(self.done_callback)` fails because you are calling `threading.Thread.start()` which only receives `self` object parameter.

- Note that when you call `new_task.start()` you are passing `new_task` as first argument implicitly, what's equivalent to: `threadhing.Thread.start(new_task)`

Also, from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> Once a thread object is created, its activity must be started by calling the thread’s start() method. This invokes the run() method in a separate thread of control.

So you have no control on how threading.Thread.run() is invoked, and you are overriding such method with different signature, by adding the _callback argument.

This doesn't make sense for me, since you are subclassing `threading.Thread` and overriding `run()` without providing its actual functionality, or splitting it in two "pieces".

In case you really need to do in that way, I would suggest not to subclass Thread and replace your Worker with something like this:

```
class Worker:

def __init__(self, _name):
    self.thread = None
    self.name = _name

def run(self, _callback):
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._p_run, args=(_callback,))
    self.thread.start()

def _p_run(self, _callback):
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print(self.name+" -- "+str(i))
        time.sleep(0.5)
    _callback()
```

You still can access `threading.Thread` interface through `Worker.thread` in case you need.

Comment: Thanks for this precise explanation. So, it's not a great idea to pass parameter through the start() method because it's handeled by the ```threading.Thread```. 

I tried this way : 
```new_task = self.to_do_list.popleft(); new_task.callback = self.done_callback; new_task.start();```
(I edited my answer with the entire code)
I'm more confortable with this implementation. It is a good way to do ?

Comment: Don't think that's a good way to go at all. In your code, ```Worker.callback``` method is dynamically created at ```Factory``` but still called within ```Worked.run```. This means that your ```threadhing.Thread``` subclass ```Worker``` is literally broken until it's handled by ```Factory```, so you would have implemented piece of code that doesn't work. Even by adding an abstract method ```Workder.callback``` still don't think is a good idea in terms of  encapsulation, readability and coupling.

Answer (score 0):

V2 :

```
import time, threading, collections

class Factory () :

    def __init__(self):
        self.to_do_list = collections.deque()

    def run(self):
        while self.to_do_list :
            new_task = self.to_do_list.popleft()
            new_task.callback = self.done_callback
            new_task.start()

    def add_worker(self, task):
        self.to_do_list.append(task)

    def done_callback(self):
            print("OK - DONE")

class Worker (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, _name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = _name

    def run(self):

        for i in range (0,5):
            print(self.name+" -- "+str(i))
            time.sleep(0.5)     
        self.callback()

factory = Factory()

worker_1 = Worker("Tomtom")
worker_2 = Worker("Nana")
worker_3 = Worker("Pikachu")

factory.add_worker(worker_1)
factory.add_worker(worker_2)
factory.add_worker(worker_3)

factory.run()
```

It works !